# c# How to add an eventhandler to many menus in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, foreach, event-handling

I'm working with the compact framework and i'm making an app for a windows mobile standard.
I have an array which contain phonenumbers, and i want to add a submenu foreach number i find in that array. These submenus must be clickable, but i can't figure out how to do it.

This is my code:

```
             // "menuItemRight" is my main menu


             // Send a message to the person
            MenuItem smsMenu = new MenuItem();
            smsMenu.Text = "Melding";
            menuItemRight.MenuItems.Add(smsMenu);

   foreach (string Number in aPhoneNumbers)
            {
                MenuItem mNumber  = new MenuItem();

                string sNumber = Number.Trim();
                mNumber.Text = sNumber.Trim();


                //SMS
                mSMS.Text = sNumber.Trim();
                smsMenu.MenuItems.Add(mSMS);
                //mNumber.Click += new EventHandler(this.MenuClick);
            }
```

So what i want is a common eventhandler, but i don't know how to implement this.

Hope someone can help me :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when the function `MenuClick` is called it recieves an object arg  (object sender) which is the MenuItem clicked.

to have the number in this function :

```
string sNumber = ((MenuItem)sender).Text;
...
```

because you stored it in the foreach loop in that property:

```
mNumber.Text = sNumber.Trim();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up your event handler so it takes the phone number (or whatever data you want to pass across) as the event arguments. You'll have to derive a new event arg based class.

Thus you have one handler in which you unpack the event args to find out which item you're dealing with.

Comment: I have more informations i want to send along.
Ex: A string with contact information. How would you do this. I can ofcourse make a global array with the number as an identification, but i guess there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers btw. It helped alot :)

Comment: @ikky - your event args can be a structure that contains all your information. You're not limited to simple types.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for `MenuItem` has what you are after (`onClick`)

You can modify your loop code slightly to put some identifier into each items `.Tag` property, and then in your event handler, cast the `sender` parameter back to a `MenuItem`.

HTH